# .hidden-phone not working for Bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am making a responsive site using Bootstrap. I am trying to hide a slider on phones. I am using the class `.hidden-phone` to achieve this. However, it is not working for me. If I use `.hidden-desktop` it hides it on the desktop site as well as the phone. Can someone check out my code and possibly demo it as well? Thanks.

[site](http://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/boot/welcome.shtml)

Code:

```
<body>
  <div class="container" style="position: relative">
<div class="carousel slide hidden-phone" id="myCarousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!--<img src="/ImageSlider/21centuryimages/sliderimages/USS.JPG" />-->
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="../ImageSlider/21centuryimages/sliderimages/Bechtel.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="../ImageSlider/21centuryimages/sliderimages/ADM.jpg" />
        </div>

    </div>
     <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>
</div>   
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: It works just fine. How are you testing it?

Comment: I am using it on my iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.2. My personal website uses the same thing and it works fine. What did you do to test it?

Comment: @Ugo It appears to work when I shrink my browser window, but not on my device

Comment: This is because iPhone 5 has a resolution of 640*1136. .hidden-phone only checks if the resolution is <= 480

Comment: What you should do is use .hidden-tablet. Alternatively, you could tweak bootstrap.css and allow larger resolutions to be considered as phones

Comment: @Ugo on my personal site I use `.hidden-phone` to hide the `.jumbotron` class and it doesn't show up on my phone. Also the menu doesn't get converted to a dropdown on my phone (from the site listed above, it does from my personal)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25554/discussion-between-matt-altepeter-and-ugo)

Answer (score 9):

For bootstrap 3.0 use class="hidden-sm"